# What is the difference between conceptual domain models, application class models, and consolidated class models?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, domain-model

I need to make these three UML diagrams for a class project, but they all seem like the exact same thing, a class diagram.

Comment: What's a consolidated class model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is the level of abstraction those models deal with the reality they try to reflect. The conceptual model is just a rough draft of the domain. You try to gather business objects (contents and relations). The application class model is one that is designed towards coding the system under consideration (SUC). The term "consolidated class model" is not a common term (at least I don't know it). But it sounds like it is the final stage of the design and matches exactly one implementation of the SUC.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure I would use the terms "rough draft". That makes it sound like the conceptual model is just a temporary sketch to be thrown away later. Although I know that is sometimes the case, often I see that the conceptual model is maintained as well, next to a logical and a technical model.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Depends on where you are in the time line. Anything starts with even less than a "rough draft". Then around that rough draft it will steer towards a real project to become "something" going through a fine design.

Answer (score 3):

Bellow a simple example of what could be the difference between a conceptual and an implementation model.

[image]

[Conceptual VS Implementation model](https://app.genmymodel.com/api/repository/orgs/Axellience/conceptualVSimplementation)

For my own experience conceptual models are much more useful than implementation models. Implementation models are much more longer to do and are only a visualization of the source code. Conceptual models should help you to better analyze, understand and communicate about the system.
A good programmer should be able to implement directly the conceptual model into source code.