# What is the difference between Conceptual Class Diagram and Detailed Class Diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, object-oriented-analysis

Can someone briefly explain the difference between a Conceptual Class Diagram and a Detailed Class Diagram?

Comment: From where did you get those attributes? I guess that each dictionary will tell you the difference between a concept and a detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between conceptual domain models, application class models, and consolidated class models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139846/what-is-the-difference-between-conceptual-domain-models-application-class-model)

Comment: It looks like this question is running out to be a collection of individual opinions.

Comment: Detailed Class Diagram?? probably you mean (DCD) Design Class Diagram.

Answer (score 3):

While a "Conceptual Class Diagram" expresses a ***conceptual (domain) model***, it's not clear what you (or your professor) mean(s) with "Detailed Class Diagram": it could refer to a (language-/platform-independent) **design model** or to an ***implementation model*** like a C++ class model or a Java class model.

See also my answer to [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265491/what-is-the-difference-between-a-domain-class-diagram-and-a-design-class-diagram?rq=1).

The one-to-many relationships between conceptual models and design models, and between design models and implementation models are illustrated in the following Figure:

[image: The one-to-many relationships in model refinement]

As an example that illustrates how the derivation chain from concept via design to implementation works, consider the following model of a people/Person concept/class:

[image: From concept via design to implementation]

Domain models are solution-independent descriptions of a problem domain produced in the analysis phase of a software engineering project. The term "conceptual model" is often used as a synonym of "domain model". A domain model may include both descriptions of the domain’s state structure (in conceptual information models) and descriptions of its processes (in conceptual process models). They are solution-independent, or ‘computation-independent’, in the sense that they are not concerned with making any system design choices or with other computational issues. Rather, they focus on the perspective and language of the subject matter experts for the domain under consideration.

In the design phase, first a platform-independent design model, as a general computational solution to the given software engineering problem, is developed on the basis of the domain model. The same domain model can potentially be used to produce a number of (even radically) different design models representing different design choices. Then, by taking into consideration a number of implementation issues ranging from architectural styles, nonfunctional quality criteria to be maximized (e.g., performance, adaptability) and target technology platforms, one or more platform-specific implementation models are derived from the design model.

Answer (score 1):

A conceptual class diagram is used to understand and analyze a problem domain. A detailed class diagram is a design artifact, where many things may have been optimized away. For example, every dog might bark, but a dog-salon application doesn't care, so it can optimize away that fact.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any standard or methodology that defines both these concepts. For example, the UML specification does not mention them. I think every answer will be subjective. I will give my own answer, based on more than 25 years of experience with IT-related modeling.

In a conceptual class diagram, every class is a concept, usually related to the business domain, the real world, e.g. Customer, Order etc. It may also show concepts that cannot be directly found in the business domain, but are needed to model the functionality of a particular application, e.g. BackupCopy. These are concepts the user of the application must understand. See also [www.agilemodeling.com](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/classDiagram.htm)

There are other types of class diagram, e.g. class diagrams that model the source code, where every class corresponds to a Java class or a C# class, or class diagrams that model the physical database structure, where every class corresponds to a database table.

Each of these types of class diagrams may or may not be detailed. If a class diagram is ***not*** detailed, it typically does not show any attributes, or only the main attributes. If a class diagram is detailed, it shows all attributes relevant for the problem at hand and the data types of these attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a conceptual class diagram is e.g. explained by Scott Ambler at http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/classDiagram.htm#ConceptualClassDiagrams.

Basically "Conceptual" here means that the content of the diagram is taken from an analytic view point that takes the "concepts" of a domain and describes them. 
For "concept" you could also say:

- thing
- item
- aspect
- object
- topic

The conceptual diagram is basically what you get if you ask people for what problem they'd like to get solved by your software. So you analyze the situation/problem by asking questions that will help you create you diagram:

- what are the things that are relevant? - these will be your candidates for classes
- what are the features of those things? - these are the candidates for your attributes
- how are the things releated to each other - e.g. is one part of another? Does it need the other? - these are the candidates for your relations
- what should you be able to do with these things in your system ? - these are the candidates for your operations

In the past this step was called OOA - object oriented analysis. The steps following this are OOD - object oriented design and OOI - object oriented implementation. Many years ago some authors proposed to create three different models for OOA/OOD and OOI. Therefore you'd have different and usually more detailed diagrams for OOD and OOI. For the term "Detailed Class Diagram" i'd guess that one of the OOD and/or OOI views would be meant. Be careful though - some of the diagrams created this way will have patterns or pattern-like ideas as a basis. You'r diagrams would tend to be very repetitive and redundant if you keep capturing such patterns in concrete diagrams for every conceptual diagram. I'd rather recommend to give just one example of how to go from problem to solution and then comment "do it this way for all other concepts that are similar".